# readdir() List files with full path - C++

Tags: c++, file, readdir, opendir

Is it possible to print files in a directory with their full path?

Expected output: `C:\Users\Gadr\Desktop\Text`

Actual output: `Text`

Code:

```
di = opendir("C:\\Users\\Gadr\\Desktop"); //specify the directory name
    
while ((dir = readdir(di)) != NULL)
{
    ptr1 = strtok(dir->d_name, ".");
    ptr2 = strtok(NULL, ".");
    if (ptr2 != NULL)
    {
        retn = strcmp(ptr2, "txt");

        if (retn == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", ptr1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Append the path yourself, you must. Look [into `<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) you should.

Comment: We would use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator instead of readdir.